# How can I link a .obj file built with VS 2010 tools into a program being built with VS 2015 tools?

Tags: c++, c, com, grpc

I've found several SO questions that indicate that what I'm after is simply not possible, and so I'm ready for that eventuality. However, I would be remiss if I did not at least throw this question out there...

A few things to keep in mind: I am not a C nor a C++ programmer of any great strength. I can hack things together, when necessary, but I typically live in the .NET world in C# - please be kind. Our client also demands that the functionality exposed by this file remain accessible, and so we cannot even just drop it.

At work, we have a C-based .obj file built with VS 2010 tools, and that version of the standard library, etc. We do not have the source available, and nobody currently at the company knows anything about it.

Currently, that obj file is built into a COM object, and we talk to it through a C# application running on .NET 4.6.1. It has worked swimmingly for years. However, we are being mandated by our client to upgrade from 4.6.1 to .NET 6. As far as I can tell, there is no COM in .NET 6. Which means that we have to come up with something else.

What I WANT to do is to build a gRPC server in C/C++ and link the obj file into it. However, the gRPC libraries require VS 2015 tools or higher (and is evidently only officially supporting VS 2017). I cannot link the file as-is into an executable that also links with gRPC libraries.

The two most viable options I see for hauling this into the modern era are:

A) Light it on fire and don't look back

B) ".NET 6 gRPC Client => .NET Framework gRPC Server => COM => myObj"

I would very much like to avoid TWO ancillary executables (gRPC server and COM) for this project. Am I overlooking something that a C/C++ developer might have in their toolbox that I am not aware of? For instance, is it possible to decompile into C/C++ code (it doesn't have to even APPROACH original) and then recompile it with modern tools?

Comment: Although that doesn't answer your question, there is COM in .NET Core 3/5/6/7 :-)

Comment: While I can add the COM reference, when I try to "dotnet build" the project, I receive an error stating that "ResolveComReference" is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild..."

Comment: Some things are not supported (it's not a 100% match), but COM is well supported overall.  You can create a COM object in many ways.

Comment: I am more willing to go with A than trying to jury rig it. You should be able to pull the assembly code from the OBJ, but trying to pull C/C++ code from an OBJ might be a tall order. Anything built with older header files is going to have problems with newer library functions due to offset changes over time. But that may not be in play with an OBJ file if the function/method references are 'fixed' at link time.

Comment: However, the fact that this is a block box is a red flag large enough to cover California in my book. You can't fix any problems that come up in the future... I would identify the interface to the OBJ file and write new code to that interface.

Comment: @SimonMourier You appear to be correct... One of my colleagues was convinced that COM didn't work in .NET 6, but I am beginning to generate evidence against his claim. I'll know fairly soon if we can keep working with our COM object. Thank you for pointing this out to me - I hadn't looked, myself. I simply took my colleague's word for it.

Comment: @SimonMourier Confirmed. It turns out we can continue to use our COM object. We just have to build our client library separately from everything else and import it as an assembly, as opposed to a project. Thank you, again, for the correction.